# How to make concurrent websocket connection with http/https proxy in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, proxy, tcpclient

I wrote an webserver with nodejs that work normally. i made a client with c# that make 100 concurrent connection to the server (with TcpClient and Socket are work good).
Now I want use http/https Proxy in TcpClient or Socket. how can i set proxy in TcpClient or socket in c# ?
Note that i dont want to use 3rd party app to stress test like THOR. i need c# app to make 100 concurrent websocket connection with proxy.

```cs
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1080);
serverStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

or

```cs
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1080);
Socket sender = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
e.RemoteEndPoint = remoteEP;
sender.ConnectAsync(e);
```